# Only summarise some levels of a group [dplyr]

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to figure (with dplyr) how to summarise just one level of a grouping variable keeping all the rest the same. For example:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- starwars %>% 
  select(height, hair_color) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(hair_color))

dat %>% 
  group_by(hair_color) %>% 
  summarise(mean_height = mean(height))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    hair_color    mean_height
#>    <chr>               <dbl>
#>  1 auburn               150 
#>  2 auburn, grey         180 
#>  3 auburn, white        182 
#>  4 black                 NA 
#>  5 blond                177.
#>  6 blonde               168 
#>  7 brown                 NA 
#>  8 brown, grey          178 
#>  9 grey                 170 
#> 10 none                  NA 
#> 11 unknown               NA 
#> 12 white                156
```

would take summarise each level of `hair_color`. But my question what if I only wanted to summarise blond hair but leave all the rest of the levels of the `hair_color`?

I see a path with `split` like below:

```
dat_split <- dat %>% 
  mutate(is_blond = ifelse(hair_color %in% c("blond"), "blond", "not_blond")) %>% 
  split(.$is_blond)


d1 <- dat_split[["blond"]] %>% 
  group_by(hair_color) %>% 
  summarise(height = mean(height))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

d2 <- dat_split[["not_blond"]] %>% 
  select(-is_blond)


dat_final <- bind_rows(d1, d2)
dat_final
#> # A tibble: 80 x 2
#>    hair_color    height
#>    <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 blond           177.
#>  2 none            202 
#>  3 brown           150 
#>  4 brown, grey     178 
#>  5 brown           165 
#>  6 black           183 
#>  7 auburn, white   182 
#>  8 auburn, grey    180 
#>  9 brown           228 
#> 10 brown           180 
#> # ... with 70 more rows
```

This however seems a bit verbose (and clunky). I'm wondering if this is a job for `rowwise` but I haven't quite yet resolved that yet in my mind.

Comment: Just a hint: Your `dat %>% mutate(is_blond = ifelse(hair_color %in% c("blond"), "blond", "not_blond")) %>% split(.$is_blond)` can be simplified to `dat %>% split(.$hair_color == "blond")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this without a grouping by `replace`ing the 'height' where the 'hair_color' is "blond" to the `mean` of 'height' for the corresponding  'hair_color'

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    mutate(height = replace(height, 
          hair_color == 'blond', mean(height[hair_color == 'blond'])))
# A tibble: 82 x 2
#   height hair_color   
#    <dbl> <chr>        
# 1   177. blond        
# 2   202  none         
# 3   150  brown        
# 4   178  brown, grey  
# 5   165  brown        
# 6   183  black        
# 7   182  auburn, white
# 8   177. blond        
# 9   180  auburn, grey 
#10   228  brown        
# … with 72 more rows
```

---

It would be more compact in `data.table` (assuming it is a numeric column)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[hair_color == 'blond', height := mean(height)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(valid = hair_color == "blond") %>%
  group_by(valid) %>%
  mutate(mean_h = ifelse(valid, mean(height), height), .keep="unused")
```

which gives

```r
# A tibble: 82 x 2
   hair_color    mean_h
   <chr>          <dbl>
 1 blond           177.
 2 none            202 
 3 brown           150 
 4 brown, grey     178 
 5 brown           165 
 6 black           183 
 7 auburn, white   182 
 8 blond           177.
 9 auburn, grey    180 
10 brown           228 
# ... with 72 more rows
```